# Отфильтровать dataframe на основе выборки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Имеется некий набор данных `tr_new`, в нем есть столбец `mcc_code`
Необходимо выбрать строки из `tr_new` в которых `mcc_code` коды встретились в более чем 60000 раз.

Я использую

```
mccmax=tr_new['mcc_code'].value_counts()>60000
```

в итоге получаю набор с `False` и `True`. А это совсем не то!

```
6010     True
5411     True   
... 
9402    False
8244    False
```

Мне нужно, просто отфильтровать список, а потом еще сгруппировать по двум полям (например `[day]` и `[mcc_code]`, получая средние значения суммы по третьему полю `[amount]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [DataFrameGroupBy.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
res = tr_new.groupby("mcc_code").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 60000)
```

Comment: О, я знал, что как-то проще всё должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое должно быть:

```
vc = tr_new['mcc_code'].value_counts()
mccmax=tr_new[tr_new['mcc_code'].isin(vc[(vc>60000).index])]
```

По шагам:

- `vc[(vc>60000).index]` - получаем собственно список самих таких mcc кодов, удовлетворяющих условию
- `tr_new['mcc_code'].isin(<полученный ранее список кодов>)` - булева маска на строки tr_new, mcc код в которых входит в наш список
- `tr_new[<булева маска>]` - собственно записи из tr_new по этой маске

Comment: Не правильно. Я до этого выполнял команду
mccmax=tr_new['mcc_code'].value_counts().to_dict()
получается что mcc кодов которые больше 60000 всего то 5
6011: 199281,
 6010: 199266,
 5411: 144202,
 4814: 120694,
 4829: 77936,

Comment: @AleksMir Немного поправил код

Comment: Проверил и этот вариант. Только заголовки полей вышли.